# Spotify API authorization + token key error - python3

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I'm running into this issue where with my script and I'm a bit stumped. I've been running this script with no problems for the past few weeks and now I'm getting a KeyError for the token.

Here's my code:

```
# IMPORTS
import os
import re
import requests
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from pprint import pprint as pp
import datetime as dt
import sys 
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
acc_path = "../../access/"
sys.path.append(acc_path)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

# Spotify Credentials
sp_url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/'
client_id = os.environ.get('SPOT_CLIENT_ID')
client_secret = os.environ.get('SPOT_CLIENT_SECRET')
output_data = '/users/Desktop/file_date.csv'
spot_scopes = os.environ.get('SPOT_SCOPES')
spot_user_name = os.environ.get('SPOT_USER_NAME') # spotify account username

sp_acc = requests.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', data = {'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'}, 
                       auth = (client_id, client_secret))
sp_bear_head = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer' + str(sp_acc.json()['access_token'])}
```

## KeyERROR

```
---> 31 sp_bear_head = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer' + str(sp_acc.json()['access_token'])}

KeyError: 'access_token'
```

I checked my bash to make sure client id, secret scopes etc. are all correct and can confirm that is not the issue. Any direction here would be very helpful!

Comment: Please add your error trace

Comment: sorry about that, key error updated

Comment: Any update on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it worked before and not now is due to the expiration of the `access token`.

The token's expiration time is determined by Spotify so you just have to work around their set constraints.

That being said, you can anticipate when a new token will need to be generated/used based on the property `expires_in` which Spotify sends back in the response when you request a token (`https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`). The `expires_in` property is an integer and it tells you how many seconds the token will be good for. As seen in [their authorization documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow), the `expires_in` property is returned with the value 3600 (seconds) or, 1 hour.

After that hour is up, use your `refresh_token` to request a new token.

Comment: Do let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! In the example I'm just trying to create the initial token, but it seems like I am unable to do so. I do refresh the token later on in the script when I am calling the api for data, but for some reason I am unable to create a token off the bat.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the access token being invalid, i.e. the access token that gets saved in `sp_acc` is not a valid token. As a result of that, you will not be able to create an initial token. What you need to do is refresh the access token before making the call of the bat. See [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) for how to go about this