# How to handle 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, spotify

Yesterday this exact code worked. Now I get the error:

> 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url:
>   https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist}/tracks?position=0

My code is:

```
CLIENT_ID = "My_Id"
CLIENT_SECRET = "MY Client_secret"

grant_type = 'client_credentials'
scope='playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private'
body_params = {'grant_type' : grant_type, 'scope':scope}

url='https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
response = requests.post(url, data=body_params, auth = (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)) 

token_raw = json.loads(response.text)
token = token_raw["access_token"]
print (token)

def addSongsToPlaylist(position):
    uris = [' My URI '] //this is a list with one item o 
    url =  'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{My PLaylist ID}/tracks?position='+str(position)
    payload = {"uris":uris}
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer "+ token}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers)
    print(r.raise_for_status())
```

This is accessing a playlist that I own and adding a track with the position to it. The scopes are correct and I still get the token, but apparently does not have the access anymore.

Do I need to do something on the Spotify dashboard?
Can you see what I am missing?

Comment: Is your playlist private? You won't be able to add a track if it is.

Comment: Can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980833/6505847)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spotify API authorization + token key error - python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980531/spotify-api-authorization-token-key-error-python3)

Comment: - The playlist is public. I have seen this other threads and they dont solve it. I am refresing the access_code before calling the add_track method. I do not want to create a user related app. This will all happen in the server side. Still can make it work...